# Is there an sample code available to capture Spring Batch Micro Metrics?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

Developing a spring boot batch application, wanted to know if there is a sample code to how to get the micro metrics discussed in the spring batch [document](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/index-single.html#built-in-metrics)?

I am looking way of getting these details per execution. Also, since I run the application using cron task schedule, can we get a separation of this data per execution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution

You need not do any coding, all readily available.

Include actuator dependency in pom

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

In the property, file add this line (instead of * you can add comma separated and security) [refrence](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html)

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
```

If your application is running on port 8080

```
http://localhost:8080/actuator/metrics/spring.batch.job
```

Will give job stats. You can query on any other metrics parameters. [Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/monitoring-and-metrics.html)

You can calculate metrics for all execution in the corn task schedule by

**First** create a custom metric endpoint.

```
@Component
@Endpoint(id = "spring.batch.executions")
public class BatchMetricEndpoint {

    @Autowired
    BatchAllJobsMetricContext batchAllJobsMetricContext;

    @ReadOperation
    public Map<String, BatchPerJobMetricContext> features() {
        return batchAllJobsMetricContext.getAll();
    }
}
```

**Second**

[Create a job listener](https://www.javadevjournal.com/spring-batch/spring-batch-listeners/)

Tap into local metric endpoint after execution.

```
@Component
public class BatchJobListener implements JobExecutionListener {

    @Autowired
    private MetricsEndpoint metricsEndpoint;

    @Autowired
    BatchAllJobsMetricContext batchAllJobsMetricContext;

    @Autowired
    BatchPerJobMetricContext batchPerJobMetricContext;

    @Override
    public void beforeJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
        MetricsEndpoint.MetricResponse metricResponse = metricsEndpoint.metric("spring.batch.job",null);
        
        String key = jobExecution.getJobParameters().getString("jobId");
        String execution = "Execution "+jobExecution.getJobParameters().getString("executionCout");
        if(batchAllJobsMetricContext.hasKey(key)){
           batchAllJobsMetricContext.get(key).put(execution,metricResponse);
        }else{
            batchPerJobMetricContext.put(execution,metricResponse);
            batchAllJobsMetricContext.put(key,batchPerJobMetricContext);
        }
        
    }

}
```

**Third**

Tap into the local metric to aggrigate data.

***Please note this way of holding metic per iteration would be expensive on memory, you would like to keep some limit and push this data to time series data source.***

[Sample code](https://github.com/ameya/springbatchwithcrontaskandactuator)

Comment: hey,I think you can help me here.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66690381/unable-to-get-spring-batch-metrics. I am able to access /actuator/metrics endpoint , but not  /actuator/metrics/spring.batch.job as it says page not found.I think the reason is because my version on spring batch is way older.So once i update and my endpoint is up,I dont need to do second and third point mentioned by you,as i think u are exposing endpoint and aggregating data.But i want to push to Prometheus and this will be done by some dependency of promotheous.So is first step sufficient for me?

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for I have put up a source here check the link under "Sample code" https://github.com/ameya/springbatchwithcrontaskandactuator